# Boss favors employees of one nationality

Tags: management

I worked for hotel x, where my boss prefers subordinates of a particular nationality.

The persons of the other nationality in the team were never promoted, appreciated, or given a pay hike, he created situations where persons of other nationalities were made to look stupid and tactfully manipulated information to make persons of the other nationality the culprit which lead to their termination.

Their nationality is in the majority.

I am trying to think through whether or not this environment is beneficial to my long term career. Can I do anything to interact with this boss effectively or grow my career given what feels like racial bias?

Comment: Leave, you're doomed otherwise.

Comment: What country are you in? Local laws will most certainly apply here.

Comment: I made a fairly comprehensive edit to remove some of the unnecessary tone and focus this more on an actionable question.

Comment: I think there were two questions in there and not just 1.  1) What about my career under such environment - which the question now reads.  2) Is there anything I can do to help my peers or the work situation that I find?

Comment: Are you of the favored nationality?

Comment: @DavidK - so what if local laws apply? Unless the OP has the time, money and inclination to attempt litigative action, the presence of laws doesn't change anything.

Comment: Surprisingly there are no local laws to cater to such a situation , and its not worth trying

Comment: @Myridium Because in many locations this is a blatant act of illegal discrimination and would't take much effort to prove it. You wouldn't have to personally sue the company but instead notify an oversight group. You could get what you want by notifying the boss's boss, or the hotel chain, or a local business bureau, or the Equal Employment Commission, all with no financial cost to yourself.

Comment: There is no such thing here in ksa, and they have finally terminated me to fill the position with a person of their nationality.

Comment: @JJ I'm sorry to hear that. Is this hotel an international hotel chain? I doubt you would be able to get your job back, but it may still be worth lodging a complaint with the company.

Comment: Its the famous chain marriott,but here in ksa local partner who has taken the franchisee is the decision maker, the hr rules support employees but the rules are just on the books nothing is practiced.my advice to all is that most of the employee hand books contain things that just are written, but never followed.

Comment: @JJ Yes, most hotels are owned and run as a franchise, but if the parent company decides that the franchise is not meeting the brand standards, they can force the owner to change or risk losing the ability to call themselves a Marriott hotel.

Comment: Bro you wrong in this regard, the parent company just is concerned about the money, as long as the local company makes a huge profit, they are happy n will not bother even if employees are ill treated

Answer (score 3):

Racial bias is big deal and I personally would not be comfortable working in a company which tolerates that irrespective of whether I am involved party or not.

However, first thing you need to do is absolutely make sure that your suspicion is rightly placed. Do you have sufficient data from past to say it without doubt that this is racial bias? Because if you escalate it and you are wrong about it, it will certainly fire back at you.

If you do, I would suggest raise it to the right supervisor or HR or Ombudsperson if you have one. Ideally a company should be able to protect your identity and make sure there are no retaliation for raising a serious issue like this. But I think you should keep an alternative job option ready just in case if this is not resolved as per your expectations.

Comment: Nationality has nothing to do with race.

Comment: @ Stephan Bijzitter, firstly, "racial bias" was the term used by O.P. (Looks like it is edited now). Secondly, your one liner may make you feel very enlightened about yourself, but it is wrong.  Nationality has a VERY STRONG correlation with race. While people of various races/countries settle all over the world, their origi nationality is still used to identify them with race (especially people from Asian, African, and Middle Eastern countries).  It is even more relevant in O.P.s context

Comment: @ Stephan Bijzitter, also down-voting because of race vs nationality difference is just ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

**Depending on your country**:
If you want to make it stop, you can take evidence of discrimination to the authorities and the person/people being discriminated against can bring it up with the authorities for a lawsuit(s).  This is a long and painful road, but if you have the backing of a portion of the staff past/present and you have hard evidence you can get the employer penalized(sometimes severely) and compensation for the discriminated employees.  You have to prove it though, not just word against word.

If you don't want to fight or your in a country that doesn't have any laws against discrimination then leave and find anywhere better.

P.S. Please note that either course will likely mean you no longer work there, unless the penalty is to take the business away from the person and give it to someone else who supports the discriminated party rights.

**Edit based on question edit**:
If you don't agree with the underlying stance of your employer it's hard to stay working for them, without becoming disgruntled, unless that particular disagreeable belief is outside the day to day work activities.  In this case I personally would have an issue benefiting over someone else's mistreatment, but that is the question you have to ask yourself if your not the discriminated race...if you are the discriminated race I wouldn't expect any different treatment for yourself.

Comment: Your right, the authorities too are of their nationality, the boss was terminated by the GM a year back.The GM resigned 2 months later,leading to the return of the old boss,thanks to his nationality people, then onwards he focuses on firing employees of other nationality for lame reasons,i hurd the rumour that i too am on his hitlist.Its a war between nationalities of pak india and egypt, in ksa.

Answer (score -3):

Any bias is really bad ,not just race or nationality .Bosses should not do this but they do .Your industry is the service industry where replacements are easy to find .Remember that in a deregulated labor market it comes down to supply and demand .If you leave causing waves or not you will be replaced within hours by your bosses favorite group. If you just slip out the door so to speak then you will always be able to get a job .If you make waves you will find it hard to get another job again .I made some waves in 1992 .The prospective payout these days balanced against probable employment leprosey will make it not worth it to kick up a fuss .The problem here is that you have no economic power .If workers are easy to find and replace then any boss anywhere can have any hiring bias without any economic downsides.You must get a job that not too many others can do ,then your skills will be respected .When things are more specialised the boss can not favour his or her pet group because the place would be empty .Do some training and get a job that not too many others can do and then you will be unlikely to encounter such problems again .

Comment: this post is rather hard to read (wall of text). Would you mind [edit]ing it into a better shape?

Answer (score -4):

In the real world the OP has the following choices:

- if they are of the boss's preferred nationality (which I **don't suspect it's the case** by the sheer existence of this question) they might do the following:

  - a) enjoy the privileged treatment and perhaps feel bad (well, they asked the question, so there is something going on)
  - b) try to fight the situation and have the boss and majority of the preferred nationality against themselves, also gaining trust of the minority is not guaranteed (OP is from the hostile camp)
- if they are in the minority (why would they asked the question) the choices are:

  - c) leaving the job for new challenges in life (I believe it's the fastest and healthiest solution for this issue)
  - d) try to fight the situation and have the boss and majority of the preferred nationality against themselves, also gaining trust of the minority is not guaranteed (they may want to keep the job and stay out of trouble)

Should OP chose for option *c)*, before leaving they might contact some anti-discrimination office and ask whether OP cannot contribute anyhow to solve the situation.

In any case I wish the OP all the best.

Comment: I downvoted this because I disagree with the advice to sit back and enjoy the benefits of discrimination on your behalf.  I think that if you see your colleagues being treated in a grossly unfair (possibly even illegal) manner, you ought to do something about it.

Comment: @dan1111, thank you for your explanation. I hope you've read my edit. Again, I strongly disagree against discrimination based on factors irrelevant to the job. But in this case theory and practice don't go along and final advice depends on how much the OP has to lose.